# Replacement for watchband loop?

Tags: clothing

The loop on my watchband broke, but the band and watch are both otherwise fine. Now when I wear it, the tail end of the watchband sticks out awkwardly.

What can I use as a replacement for the loop without having to buy a replacement watch or watchband?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Velcro with an adhesive backing may do the trick. You just stick one "dot" on the tail of the watchband, and the other on the watch band so that it aligns with the first dot when you're wearing your watch.

Be careful when putting on and taking off your watch not to snag the Velcro dot that is on the tail. It may come off over time.

[image]

Comment: @Gwenn Thanks for marking this as the answer!

Answer (score 3):

I've used thin no damage hair elastics like these:

[image]

Preferably use thin ones because they don't create pressure on your wrist underneath the watch band.

No damage ones because I personally find the hair elastics with metal a bit uncomfortable.

Simply loop the elastics around the watch band and then it should hold the free end in place for you.

Answer (score 1):

I would use use a small rubber band

Comment: This is a little short and unprecises. Could you please clarify how to use it,  maybe include a drawing or something like that?

Comment: Well this is not exactly a though question and although I agree my answer is really short I won't draw anything to explain how to replace a rubber loop by another rubber loop... The same way I don't think this deserved a question, I don't think the answer needs more detail. Feel free to flag answer though.